# Confirm box cancel function does the same thing as OK

Tags: javascript, confirm

I would like someone to tell me why the cancel button redirects me to Youtube instead of cancelling out the operation.

```
function link(){
    var r = confirm("Are you leaving?");
    if (r = true) {
        a.link("http://www.youtube.com");}
    else {
        return true;}   

}
```

`<a href="http://www.youtube.com" onclick="link()">Youtube</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Because by omission of one equal sign, you set `r` to `true` here:

```
if (r = true) {
```

Just change it to:

```
if (r == true) {
```

or

```
if (r === true) {
```

or just to

```
if (r) {
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function link(){
    var r = confirm("Are you leaving?");

    // if user clicks ok he'll be redirected to youtube
    // as "r" will be truthy

    if (r) { // this means user clicked ok
        return a.link("http://www.youtube.com");
    }
    else {
        return false; // and this means user clicked cancel so he'll not be redirected so this needs to be set to false
    }   

}
```

`confirm` will return true or false but in your code you're asigning true to `r` so it'll never work.

As I wrote in the comments above, you need to set the return inside the else statement to be false.

And instead of using `a.link()` I recommend you use `window.location` for example.

```js
function link(){
    
    var r = confirm("Are you leaving?");

    if(r){
        var redirect = window.location = "http://youtube.com";
        return redirect;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
        
}
```

```html
<a href="http://youtube.com" onclick="return link()">click here to be redirected!</a>
```

Comment: To sum it up, I want to cancel out the operation. While both of you gave me some valued insight on the if function and took the time to reply, both of you still haven't answered the question; how do you cancel out the operation is what I'm asking.

Comment: Thanks, peace and love!